# Wordpress login fail after .htaccess domain redirect

Tags: htaccess

I use .htaccess to redirect requests to my (new) domain to another domain hosted on different server. The file contains:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?amazon40\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://steamsigs.com/amazon40/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The redirection works fine. The home page is redirected to steamsigs.com/amazon40 and wordpress login page shows up correctly (steamsigs.com/amazon40/wp-login.php). But the acutual login process doesn't work. It does not show the control panel and keeps on redirecting to the login page. Could be that something's interfering with the GET/POST vars but I'm not sure about this.

I'd appreciate any your help to resolve this.

Comment: Does it work when you remove the htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

Did you also [change the site URL in the settings](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/recover-wordpress-blog-from-an-inactive-domain-name/5947#5947)? WordPress needs correct settings for these, otherwise the login page on `steamsigs.com` will still do the post to `amazon40.com` and you'll never get the correct cookies set.